# MySQL, if a value is in one of two columns, return the value from the other one

Tags: sql, mysql

This might be an easy one, but I'm not really experienced with sql.

I have a table with two user_id columns, user1 and user2. This table contains some compared values between the two users.

I want to send in an user id, and return all the id's from the other user when the sent user is either user1 or user2.

I guess some sort of if test would do the trick, but I don't know how to do this in SQL.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
SELECT user1 FROM TAB WHERE user2=id
UNION ALL
SELECT user2 FROM TAB WHERE user1=id
```

Comment: is there to filter this sql statement result to show only the objects that are NOT id?

Answer (score 1):

codaddict's solution would work I would however go with the following:

```
select if(user1 = userparam, user2, user1) as user
from table
where user1 = userparam or user2 = userparam
```

EDIT: Replaced the case with an if function.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is:

```
SELECT IF(user1 = ID, user2, user1) AS other_user FROM table WHERE user1 = ID OR user2 = ID
```